# Get the percentage of points based on a Javascript calculation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, math

I need to get a percentage to update a progress bar that indicates the points that i have. I update it by passing it as WIDTH a percentage I get from a JS operation to a DIV. I have 3 levels to upgrade the bar on, each level has a point target, beyond that target you move on to the next level. My levels are as follows:

```
cost level1 = 0-999
cost level2 = 1000-1999
cost level3 = 2000-4999
```

My goal is for level 1 to get a percentage ranging from 0% up to 33.33%. For level 2 obtain a percentage that is compressed from 33.34% up to 66.6% and for level 3 obtain a percentage that is compressed between 66.7% and 99.9%.

I tried to do the following:

```
const maxPointForLevel1 = 999
const maxPointForLevel2 = 1999
const maxPointForLevel3 = 4999

const checkTierLevel = () => {
    if(currentPoints >= 0 && currentPoints < 1000){
        return (currentPoints / maxPointForLevel1) * 100 / 3
    } else if(currentPoints > 999 && currentPoints < 2000){
        return (currentPoints / maxPointForLevel2) * 100 / 1.5
    } else if(currentPoints >= 2000 && currentPoints < 5000){
        return (currentPoints / maxPointForLevel3) * 100 
    }
}
```

However, these reasoning only work for the first and second level, but the operation does not work well for the third level. Perhaps because the third level, unlike the first and second, has a higher range, i.e. between 2000 and 4999.
Thanks to anyone who can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to add more levels, it will require more changes to write in your code.
Another issue will be when someone will ask you to change 1999 to 2000.

That's why I prefer to write the levels in an array and read it.

If you wish to change the ranges, you only need to change it there.

```js
const levels = [0, 999, 1999, 4999];

function convertNumToPercentageInRange(num, range) {
  const { min, max} = range;
  return (100) * (num - min) / (max - min) ;
}

const getMinMaxRange = (number) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < levels.length - 1; i++) {
        if (levels[i] <= number && number <= levels[i+1]) {
            return {
                min: levels[i],
                max: levels[i+1]
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

const checkTierLevel = (currentPoints) => {
    const range = getMinMaxRange(currentPoints);
    if (!range) {
        if (currentPoints < levels[0]) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (currentPoints > levels[levels.length - 1]) {
            return 100;
        }
    }
    return convertNumToPercentageInRange(currentPoints, range);
}
```

getMinMaxRange gets current points and returns its min and max in the levels array.

convertNumToPercentageInRange gets the current points and a range and convert this points to precepercentages.

```
checkTierLevel(-500) // 0
checkTierLevel(0) // 0
checkTierLevel(999) // 100
checkTierLevel(1499) // 50
checkTierLevel(4700) // 90
checkTierLevel(4999) // 100
checkTierLevel(6000) // 100
```